# How to disable only extension part of file name in input box using angular?

Tags: angular

I have a form input field with filename and it is 2 way binded with custom validation attached to that field to check whether file name already exists.In my scenario I don't want to allow user to edit the file extension how can I disable a part of file name in my template?
I can not split that new_name in component as appUniqueName is attached to that field it will not work properly, what is the alternate way?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter new name" [(ngModel)]="new_name" #new_nameName="ngModel" id="new_name" name="new_name" required appUniqueName autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Have you tried `readonly` or `disabled` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an intermediate property with a getter and setter. The setter will add the file extension to the string and store it in your original property `new_name`. The getter returns your property without but removes the file extension.

```
private new_name: string;
get newNameWithoutExtension() 
{ 
  return this.new_name.substring(0, new_name.length - 4); // remove latest chars
}
set newNameWithoutExtension(value: string) {
  this.new_name = value + '.txt' // whatever your file extension is
}
```

After that you can bind using `[(ngModel)]="newNameWithoutExtension"` and only edit the name without the extension, but still have the full name in the property `new_name`.

Comment: appUniqueName is a validator which is recieving file name without extension which is not what i want.